# Beautiful Soup page loop

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I just start doing Python for the first time. I try to take the data out from a couple accommodation page. Still, I couldn't figure out on how am I suppose to loop the data from the next page with same URL. If you could help me out,thanks in advance. This is my cod

```
     from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup 
     from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
     import re
       my_url='https://www.hipflat.co.th/en/search/sale/condo_y/any_r1/any_r2/any_p/any         _b/any_a/any_w/any_o/any_i/100.62442610451406,13.77183154691727_c/12_z/list_v'
     https://www.hipflat.co.th/en/search/sale/condo_y/any_r1/any_r2/any_p/any_b/any_a/any_w/any_o/any_i/100.62442610451406,13.77183154691727_c/12_z/list_v
     # grabbing the page
     uClient = uReq(my_url)
     page_html = uClient.read()
     uClient.close()
     #html parsing
     page_soup = soup(page_html,"html.parser")

     #Grab Data
     Condo = page_soup.findAll("li",{"class":"listing"})
         for Con in Condo:
             Name = Con.findAll("div",{"class":"listing-project"})[0].text.strip()
             Description = Con.p.text
             Price = Con.findAll("div",{"class":"listing-price"})[0].text.strip()
             Type = Con.findAll("ul",{"class":"listing-detail"})[0].text.replace("\n","")
             Type = re.split(r'(bed|bath|m2)',Type)
             Data = {"Name" : Name,"Description" : Description,"Price":Price,"Bed":Type[0],"Bath":Type[2],"Area(m2)":Type[4]}
```

Also if I edit Dictionary Data. I also got IndexError: list index out of range

```
  Data = {"Name" : Name,"Description" : Description,"Price":Price,"Bed":Type[0],"Bath":Type[2],"Area(m2)":Type[4],"Floor":Type[6]}
```

Comment: This page is dynamically generated so you have to analyze JSON server responses, but not html.

Comment: @RomanMindlin How can I do that and what packages do I required to get the job done here? Can you point me to the right direction maybe what should I search for in google. Thanks

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no short answer to your question. You should either analyze this page's code (with developer's tools in browser) and find data source or use Selenium to simulate your clicks and scrap all pages.

Comment: I start try using selenium for clicking the next page. Still, I can't figure out how to loop this thing and adding dict together.